# php mail in object oriented

Tags: php, oop

I want to send mail through php code.I'm familiar with procedural but I'm newbie to object oriented(OOP).My mailing code is working well in procedural bt not in OOP.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];
include "config.php";
 $sql = $conn->query("insert into message(name,email,phone,message) values ('$name','$email','$phone','$message')");

 $from = $email;
     $to= 'web@gmail.com';
     $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
echo     $body = "
 Hello Sir,
 I request you to give authority to access parkintrade website as guest     user.

  user Details
   Name    : $name
   Email   : $email
   Phone   : $phone
   message : $message
 ";
  $body.="\nThis is an auto generated email so please do not reply to this email.
  Thank you,
  $name\n";

 echo  $sentmail = mail( $to,"Welcome ", $body, $headers1 );
}
```

Comment: _"Guide me what to do send mail in OOP"_ With 707 points I feel I can say this without regrets: **NO**, SO is NOT here to convert your code or provide you with a tutorial, google it and learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Enlighten yourself with  [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).

Comment: got "Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found" even I copied class.phpmailer.php

Comment: Like @Epodax said __SO is NOT here to convert your code or provide you with a tutorial, google it and learn it__